# How can I animate using SPPLOT?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sp

I have a shapefile with 5000+ polygons.

I have a netCDF file with timeseries data for several variables with one common key with the shapefile.

## Static Map

For any particular time, I plot a static map by

- Merging netCDF data for one timestep into the shapefile
- Plot the shapefile using `spplot`

## Animation

Now, I want to create an animation for a small time period.

For `ggplot2`, there are packages such as gganimate etc.

But, how can I do this using `spplot`?

P.S. GGPLOT2 is too slow for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [animation package](https://yihui.name/animation/)?

Remember that spplot is a lattice based function, so if you're doing this in a function you'll need to print() inside the function.